# Getting blank page on authentication on stripe payment gateway

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

We are using stripe payment gateway in our app. Everything is working fine without authentication payment. But with authentication payment, we always get a blank page on the test and live both modes.

Can anyone tell me what the possible problem is?

below is my code

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Stripe.setDefaultPublishableKey("kljkahsha7878asjdba78")
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [cardTextField, payButton])
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.spacing = 20
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(stackView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: view.leftAnchor, multiplier: 2),
      view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: stackView.rightAnchor, multiplier: 2),
      stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, multiplier: 2),
    ])
    startCheckout()
    
}

lazy var cardTextField: STPPaymentCardTextField = {
  let cardTextField = STPPaymentCardTextField()
  return cardTextField
}()

lazy var payButton: UIButton = {
  let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
  button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
  button.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
  button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
  button.setTitle("Pay now", for: .normal)
  button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pay), for: .touchUpInside)
  return button
}()

func displayAlert(title: String, message: String, restartDemo: Bool = false) {
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}

func startCheckout() {
    let obj_OperationWeb = OperationWeb()
    //        DesignModel.startActivityIndicator()
    DesignModel.StartBtnActivity(btnActivity)
    obj_OperationWeb.callRestApiForPayment(API_PINTENT, methodType: .POST, parameters: dictParams, onCompletion: { (dictResponse) in
        print(dictResponse)
        if !dictResponse.isEmpty {
            //userdetails
            if (dictResponse[RES_status]?.isEqual(RES_SUCCESS))! {
                DesignModel.StopBtnActivity(self.btnActivity, completionType: .COMPLETION_SUCCESS)
                let clientSecret = dictResponse.isKeyNull("data") ? "" : dictResponse["data"] as! String
                print("Created PaymentIntent")
                self.paymentIntentClientSecret = clientSecret
                
            } else if (dictResponse[RES_status]?.isEqual(API_STATUS_INVALID_TOKEN))! {
                DesignModel.StopBtnActivity(self.btnActivity, completionType: .COMPLETION_SUCCESS)
                
                
                self._IKAlertActionView.ShowikTopAlertSingleButton(MSG_TITLE, message: "Payment intent not created (unable to load page)", image: APP_IMAGE_FOR_ALERT, okButtontext: MSG_OK_BUTTON, alertPosition: .ALERT_TOP, alertType:.DUMMY)
                return }
            else  {
                DesignModel.StopBtnActivity(self.btnActivity, completionType: .COMPLETION_FAIL)
                self._IKAlertActionView.ShowikTopAlertSingleButton(MSG_TITLE, message: dictResponse[RES_msg] as! String, image: APP_IMAGE_FOR_ALERT, okButtontext: MSG_OK_BUTTON, alertPosition: .ALERT_TOP, alertType:.DUMMY)
                return
            }
        }
        else {
            DesignModel.StopBtnActivity(self.btnActivity, completionType: .COMPLETION_FAIL)
            
            self._IKAlertActionView.ShowikTopAlertSingleButton(MSG_TITLE, message: MSG_ERR_CONNECTION, image: APP_IMAGE_FOR_ALERT, okButtontext: MSG_OK_BUTTON, alertPosition: .ALERT_TOP, alertType:.DUMMY) }
    }) { (errorCode) in
        DesignModel.StopBtnActivity(self.btnActivity, completionType: .COMPLETION_FAIL)
        
        self._IKAlertActionView.ShowikTopAlertSingleButton(MSG_TITLE, message: MSG_ERR_CONNECTION, image: APP_IMAGE_FOR_ALERT, okButtontext: MSG_OK_BUTTON, alertPosition: .ALERT_TOP, alertType:.DUMMY)
    }

    
    
}

@objc
func pay() {
  guard let paymentIntentClientSecret = paymentIntentClientSecret else {
      return;
  }
  // Collect card details
  let cardParams = cardTextField.cardParams
  let paymentMethodParams = STPPaymentMethodParams(card: cardParams, billingDetails: nil, metadata: nil)
  let paymentIntentParams = STPPaymentIntentParams(clientSecret: paymentIntentClientSecret)
  paymentIntentParams.paymentMethodParams = paymentMethodParams

  // Submit the payment
  let paymentHandler = STPPaymentHandler.shared()
  paymentHandler.confirmPayment(withParams: paymentIntentParams, authenticationContext: self) { (status, paymentIntent, error) in
    switch (status) {
    case .failed:
        self.displayAlert(title: "Payment failed", message: error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
        self._IKAlertActionView.ShowikTopAlertSingleButton("Payment Fail", message: "Unknown Eror", image: APP_IMAGE_FOR_ALERT, okButtontext: MSG_OK_BUTTON, alertPosition: .ALERT_TOP, alertType:.DUMMY)
        break
    case .canceled:
        self.displayAlert(title: "Payment canceled", message: error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
        self._IKAlertActionView.ShowikTopAlertSingleButton("Payment Cancel", message: "Unknown Eror", image: APP_IMAGE_FOR_ALERT, okButtontext: MSG_OK_BUTTON, alertPosition: .ALERT_TOP, alertType:.DUMMY)
        break
    case .succeeded:
        self.displayAlert(title: "Payment succeeded", message: paymentIntent?.description ?? "")
        self._IKAlertActionView.ShowikTopAlertSingleButton("Payment Success", message: "Done", image: APP_IMAGE_FOR_ALERT, okButtontext: MSG_OK_BUTTON, alertPosition: .ALERT_TOP, alertType:.DUMMY)
        break
    @unknown default:
        fatalError()
        break
    }
  }
}


extension PaymentVC1: STPAuthenticationContext {
func authenticationPresentingViewController() -> UIViewController {
    return self
} }
```

Here is the video of app! here we are not getting OTP (authentication page).

[image: Actual image of app for better understading]

Comment: since this is also happening in test mode, it could be related to your app hierarchy possibly. 1/ How is your green view controller presented? 2/ Also, in test mode, do you see any errors or warnings? 3/ Can you try with the 3220 and 3155 test cards from https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards-responses in test mode?

Comment: 1.I changed the hierarchy then after getting same. 2.even in live mode getting this with multiple card type and not showing any error or warning. 3. yes I tried test card but same problem.